# Does time.sleep() stop all executions?

Tags: python, time, sleep

In my complex python program, when it's running, I have a piece of code that executes every 3 seconds that prints the program's progress as the percentage of the execution that's finished like so:

```
while len(dequeueingFinishedList)!=10:
    print(str(len(masterListCSV_RowsListFinished)/float(len(masterListCSV_RowsList))*100) + "% done.")
    time.sleep(3)
```

Is the `time.sleep()` function going to slow down my program? I read the that sleep function suspends execution. If it is slowing down my program, is there a more correct way of printing the progress to me every 3 seconds?

Comment: it wlil sleep, as if you were asleep.

Comment: I assume there is another thread actually doing the work?

Comment: @njzk Yes, I have about 10 threads doing their own jobs.

Comment: Yes, it blocks there until the time expires.  To use a timer for output while keeping the program going, use a thread with `threading.Timer`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
from time import time

prev = time()
while True:
    now = time()
    if now - prev > 3:
        print 'report'
        prev = now
    else:
        pass
        # runs
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, and it's so simple! Thanks. :D

Comment: that's horrible. You are basically no-oping constantly, while `sleep` woul just tell the scheduler to stop wasting time on this thread for 3 seconds.

Comment: You're basically just replicating `time.sleep()` for no reason what so ever. What's the purpose of this? It doesn't even answer the question *does it stop all execution*...

Comment: to avoid drift, use a deadline: `if timer() > deadline: deadline += 3`

Answer (score 4):

[`time.sleep(seconds)`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html?highlight=time#time.sleep) will stop execution on the *current* thread. Therefore, it will completely stop your program on that thread: nothing else will happen until those seconds pass.

You don't have to worry about this. If the program uses threading, then the other threads shouldn't halt.

Comment: This was partially the case for me. My 10 other threads turned out to be uninterrupted, but when the time came at the end to gather all my data and put it into one final CSV in the main thread, that's where this was being slowed. Thanks for the useful info! :D

Comment: @Rafi How are you threading the application? Are you using a `multiprocess.Pool`? I'm somewhat confused as to why you would meed to halt execution on the main thread, and there is likely a way where you can be more efficient

Comment: No, I'm not using that, I'm just creating new threads using `threading.Thread()`. I'm using these threads to crawl a csv of urls to scrape emails from them using mechanize and regular expression.

Comment: @Rafi That sounds interesting :) It may be a good read for you to get into `multiprocessing`. It provides many useful ways of creating threads, and standardizing operations. It's a standard python library that is superseding `threading`. Here's the relevant docs: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot man, I definitely gotta make this email crawler go faster. So far, it's at 500 emails a minute. Email website directories tend to purposely increase the loading time of a web page if they detect high traffic from one location.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `time.sleep` will halt your program.

Use `time.time` in your loop and check when three seconds have passed.

Comment: Can you point to some proof that it does this? Or do you mean that it just stops execution on that thread?

Comment: @cmcnphp Yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is with [signal](https://docs.python.org/2/library/signal.html)

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print i
    if i>100000000:
        raise Exception("the end")
    else:
        signal.alarm(3)      

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, handler)   
signal.alarm(3)     

i=0
while True:
   i+=1
```

Comment: Beware that using signal handler for any heavy task could be disastrous. First, `alarm(2)` is not guaranteed to be re-entrant and is unsafe in signal handler. Second, Python `raise` probably does a lot of unsafe actions for signal handler. Furthermore in the case of Python, if your program receives a signal during a slow system call such as `read(2)` and `write(2)`, [the syscall appears to block signals until completion](https://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/python/SiginterruptGotcha), which will cause the alarm to miss.